# Expose functions to EEx templates

Tags: templates, elixir

I am using `EEx.eval_file` and `EEx.eval_string` because I have no access to the templates during compile time and want to expose some functions that can be called from inside the templates.

What I **could** so it to pass a reference using the bindings (`test: &test/1`) but then I would have to call them like this which is not great from a user perspective: `<%= test.("Hello") %>`

Are there any other ways I could try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not documented AFAICS but `EEx.eval_string` internally calls `Code.eval_quoted/3` and the third argument (`options`) is passed as is to that function. `Code.eval_quoted/3` accepts a `functions` keyword argument in `options` which contains the functions to import:

> `:functions` - a list of tuples where the first element is a module and the second a list of imported function names and arity; the list of function names and arity must be sorted

<sup>[Source](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_string/3)</sup>

Example:

```
iex(1)> EEx.eval_string ~s|<%= length("foo") %>|, [], functions: [{String, [length: 1]}]
"3"
```

Comment: It works (as usual with your answers)! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another approach is to add `<% import String %>` at the top of the template and then evaluate that. The benefit is that it works for both compiled and evaluated templates.